# Possible to exclude in Bash regex?

Tags: regex, linux, bash

If I have the following files

```
aaa-a1
aaa-a2
c
d
eee-e1
```

Is it then possible to write a regex for `ls` that lists all files except for `aaa*` and `eee*` ?

Had it been JavaScript I would have written

```
^/(?!aaa|eee)([a-z0-9]+)$
```

but `ls ^/(?!aaa|eee)([a-z0-9]+)$` is not a valid regex in Bash.

Comment: Existing answer is good, just a reminder that if you're using this for a script then you should [avoid parsing the output of ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: `find -type f ! -regex '.*\(aaa.*\|eee.*\)'` is also a possibility

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using extended glob pattern in bash like this:

```bash
shopt -s extglob
ls !(@(aaa|eee)-*)

c      d
```

Here:

- `shopt -s extglob` enables extended glob
- `!` is a negation
- `@(...|...)` selects one of the alternatives

Answer (score 2):

`ls` doesn't use regexps (or globs or any other pattern matching). Your **shell** is the thing that generates the list of file names which it then passes to `ls` to try to print and then `ls` will succeed in doing so if the list is short enough or will fail if the list exceeds `ARG_MAX`. If you use `printf '%s\n' *foo*` instead of `ls *foo*` then you won't encounter that limitation because `printf` is a builtin (which `ARG_MAX` doesn't apply to) while `ls` is not and so, unlike `ls`, `printf` won't choke no matter how many file names the shell passes to it.

If I were doing this then for conciseness I'd just do:

```
$ printf '%s\n' * | grep -Ev '^(aaa|eee)'
c
d
```

if the file names couldn't contain newlines or this otherwise, using GNU grep for `-z`:

```
$ printf '%s\0' * | grep -zEv '^(aaa|eee)'
c<NUL>d<NUL>
```

That way you can just use whatever simple, commonly known ERE you like in whatever shell you like to do the match.